# Taskqueue in python on gae won't work

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a problem about the taskqueue..

here's my code for my taskqueue:

```py
taskqueue.add(url='/taskaddroom', params={'code': self.request.get('code'),
    'room_type': self.request.get('room_type'),
    'start_date': self.request.get('start_date'),
    'end_date': self.request.get('end_date'),
    'net_price': self.request.get('net_price'),
    'num_person': self.request.get('num_person'),
    'max_adult': self.request.get('max_adult'),
    'max_children': self.request.get('room_type'),
    'num_slots': self.request.get('num_slots')})
```

here's my code for my handler:

```py
class TaskAddRoom(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        code = self.request.get('code'), 
        room_type = self.request.get('room_type'), 
        start_date = self.request.get('start_date'), 
        end_date = self.request.get('end_date'), 
        net_price = self.request.get('net_price'), 
        num_person = self.request.get('num_person'), 
        max_adult = self.request.get('max_adult'), 
        max_children = self.request.get('max_children')
        slots = self.request.get('num_slots')

        for a in slots:
            add = AddRooms(code, room_type, start_date, end_date, net_price, num_person, max_adult, max_children)
            result = add.addrooms()
```

my problem is the TaskAddRooms class it wont work.. and give me no signs of error...

Thanks..

Comment: have you set up an appropriate handler mapping for /taskaddroom in your app.yaml? you can easily test this by adding a get handler to your class and typing the url into a browser

Comment: another thing regarding the line "for a in slots". slots will be a string (since self.request.get returns a string), so "for a in slots" will iterate through each character in the string. i assume this isn't the desired effect?!

Comment: what do you mean by an appropriate handler mapping?..

in comes with my code "for a in slots" I convert it to "for a in range(1, int(slots))".. Still won't work

Comment: "give me no signs of error" - you are great developer!

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry Don't mock people that try to learn. We are not all that Great as you!

User1881959 can you put some logging inside the handler to see if the handler is called?

Comment: Can you post the content of your app.yaml file, and the declaration of your WSGIApplication.